# Download file in xamarin forms on android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I'm trying to download a file from the server. After download, I don't get any errors so I suppose that file is downloaded but I can't find it in any folder. Is it because of an android emulator? I'm currently using Android 9.0 API 28.

```cs
public void DownloadFile(string url, string cookie)
{
  string pathToFolder-Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
  try
  {
    WebClient webClient=new WebClient();
    InitiatesSSLTrust();
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "JSESSIONID="+cookie);
    webclient.DownloadFileCompleted+=new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
    string pathToNewFile=Path.Combine(pathToFolder, "plik.pdf");
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), pathToNewFile);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    if(OnFileDownloaded != null)
    {
      OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to use adb to copy the file from the emulator filesystem

Comment: As far as I remember `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` is private to the App.

Comment: You get no exception? Did you get the dialog asking for permissions to access that folder? What did the application output say at the time of download? You can see this project that used MyDocuments for storing a TXT file https://github.com/nathanvmag/NaveApp/blob/7cec73af4aa1bad43c22a6bfbef2663e1ed962ad/NaveApp/Droid/Natives.cs Also permissions in Android manifest for INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string pathToFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

the path will like

```
"/data/user/0/packagename/files/plik.pdf"
```

As you save it to [Internal Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage),you couldn't see the files without root permission,if you want to view it,you could use `adb` tool (application signed by Android Debug)

```
adb shell
run-as packagename
cd /data/data/packagename
cd files
ls
```

then you could see the `plik.pdf`

or you could save it to [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows),then you could find it in your device File Manager:

```
//"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files/plik.pdf"
string path = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).ToString();
```